# Pandas Memory Issue when loading JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to load in the JSON file and convert it to a csv formatted txt file (tab-delimited). When I try to open this JSON file of 4 GB with pandas read JSON (pd.read_json) this takes up a lot more memory than the original file was (about 24 GB) and it gets stuck in some way. Does anyone know a fix for this?

This is what my code is looking like right now:

```
df = pd.read_json(f"txtfiles/{file}.json",lines=True)
df.to_csv(fr'txtfiles/{file}.txt', index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')
```

Comment: show the json sample, it depends on the actual structure. Look into read_json _orient_ argument